# How to open gallery via intent without result?

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I have a kind of an ApplicationLauncher that has to start the build-in gallery. But I don't want to get any result from that gallery. I just want to start it and want my "Launcher" to close after that.

What I have tried:

```
    Intent intentBrowseFiles = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intentBrowseFiles.setType("image/*");
    intentBrowseFiles.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intentBrowseFiles);
```

but it doesn't even work with this flag. As soon as I click on a pic in the gallery, it closes and returns to my "Launcher". Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 4):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to start it and want my "Launcher" to close after that.

Call `finish()` after you call `startActivity()` to close up your "Launcher".

Comment: thanks for your comment. If I do so, my App closes ofcourse, but the gallery keeps closing after I click on pic and i´m landing on the androids main-menu

Comment: @max: Well, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I would like to start the gallery as a new application with all its functionality like when i open the gallery from the androids main-menu. I dont want any results or smt like that... i just want it to open and keep going... but like i said, it closes when i click on a pic =/

Comment: @max: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not your answer, then. AFAIK, there is no documented `Intent` to launch the Gallery application. Hence, I suggest you discontinue this feature.

Comment: So there's no way of launching the gallery app from my own application like if the gallery was launched from the launcher (without the intent to choose an image, just browsing through images)?

Answer (score 2):

Since it doesn't seem to be possible to open the gallery via an `Intent` to just browse pictures (without the intent to select one which is then passed back to your application) like when starting the gallery from the launcher, the only solution I found is to explicitly state the package and `Activity` name in the `Intent`. For example:

```
// For Android 4.0 (Samsung Galaxy Nexus)
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gallery3d", "com.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery");
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
// For Samsung Galaxy S2
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.cooliris.media", "com.cooliris.media.Gallery");
startActivity(intent);
```

Of course this solution isn't flexible at all and you would have to keep a list of package/activity names in your application and sending Intents (catching `ActivityNotFoundException`) until you found the right one.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the path to open the gallery?

Answer (score 1):

Calling finish in your launcher and clearing the activity stack *may* help, but your problem is probably related to the fact that your intent is Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Looks like you're trying to get content from the gallery, and that is what it is doing. Try ACTION_VIEW instead.

Comment: Hey Jon, I also tried ACTION_VIEW with an Runtime-exception as result: "unable to start activity"