# In gridview , i want to set an image and a name to that image?

Tags: android

I successfully set the image from the adapter. I want to set the name below the image. How to do this. The names are stored in a string array. The code snippet from the adapter is as below.

```
if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialise some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 6 , 4 ,2);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
```

also i want the images and the image title to be as close as in the image in the link below.

[How to implement custom device photos gallery for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438935/how-to-implement-custom-device-photos-gallery-for-android)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Better you can create a new layout where you have a ImageView and TextView in Linear layout.( TextView is kept under ImageView).

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout,
                    null);//gridview_layout is the layout tht you have created.
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Sample);//Sample is the textView id
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sampleim);//sampleim is the imageview id
            textView.setText(names[position]);//names:your string array of names
            imageView.setImageResource(imageids[position]);//imageids: String array of images.
            view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            return view;
        }
```