# how to decrease the space between the images in the image below? Is there any way to make the spae zero ? so that the images are side by side?

Tags: android, image

[image]

Edit:how to make my screen like this?

[How to implement custom device photos gallery for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438935/how-to-implement-custom-device-photos-gallery-for-android)

The xml is in the below link

http://pastebin.com/WdgEBQUY

Comment: See if you have some padding or so. If you have the XML post it here, so that we can see where you can optimize for this view.

Comment: If you can share some code , we will be able to help better ! Are you using GridView?

Comment: XML is not available, can you please add it to question only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did this with grid view. Check your XML if it has any property like

```
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

try to change these properties and also change  if your code contain the code of this type

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

1. Use GridView set numbers of column for 3
2. Use coge abowe to get screen size, divide width by 3 and zet size of column
3. Set align to center for elemennt in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the padding, may be in your java code, following line of line,

> imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

convert it into,

> imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);