# How to open an image file only using Built in gallery android?

Tags: android

Hi I want to Open a image only using built in Gallery in android. Now I'm using the following code, If i click the button it shows the menu which contains the third party tools installed to open the image. I want only built-in gallery, Is there any option to hide the other Third party tools are I can open directly with Gallery without showing the menu.

```
package com.example.gallery;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
Button bt;
private String selectedImagePath;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_picture);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                    // select a file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                            SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because on click of button you are passing intent in which you are setting its type  `intent.setType("image/*");` and `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` so it will show list of app installed on device.

If you want to open only gallery direct then you should pass intent for gallery only.

Comment: Thank you. For gaalery what is the intent I should pass? Can you please post the Intent for Gallery?

Comment: look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864860/how-to-open-gallery-via-intent-without-result

Comment: @Krishna  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); or Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                  "content://media/internal/images/media")); will be useful to you. Let me know whether this helps you or not.