# Issue when fetch image from gallery

Tags: android

Currently, I am using below `code` to fetch an image from gallery

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);            
 galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Constants.SELECT_GALLERY);
```

But the issue is that its also showing `GIF` file, when open gallery, I want only image files, I have also tried this

```
galleryIntent.setType("image/jpeg, image/png");
```

But the result is same. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please post your whole code with callback

Comment: @AJTEST, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14395059/4748607)

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

This solution is from my own project usage:

```
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    .setType("image/*")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
```

then `startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Constants.SELECT_GALLERY);`

The `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `image/*` asks android to get anything that can open it, i.e. gallery, and the Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES retruns those intent only those MIME types to be selectable.

This will help.